# Subscription to a post request is not working in Angular

Tags: angular, publish-subscribe

I have following section of code in my Angular application which makes a call to a Spring REST Service running on port 8080. The issue with the code is that the Subscription to this POST request is not working:

```
this.http.post<{'username': string,'score': number}>('http://localhost:8080/setScore',{
        'username': username,
        'score': score
    },{
       headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization',authToken)
    }).subscribe(data => {
        console.log('DATA');
    }, error => {
        console.log('ERROR');
    });
```

It is not logging DATA or ERROR in console.

Comment: any other error you are getting in console? or in network tab of devtools?

Comment: maybe request is pending?

Comment: No, there is no error in the console. It is sending request to the service but not running the code in case of success or error.